# Is it possible to use a script to throw an error in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, error-handling

In the build phases section of Xcode, it is possible to run a script during or after the build process to do whatever.

I am wondering if it is possible to whip up a script that could analyze the code in my project and throw warnings if something isn't right. Kind of like adding my own extra set of rules that if broken, Xcode wouldn't build the app.

Is this possible? Can someone get me going in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possible:

1. Use your own code analyzer or smth else to check your code
2. Print errors/warnings in script phase like "error: some error in code"

Emitting errors in Xcode script phase

https://medium.com/@mateuszmatrejek/emitting-errors-and-warnings-in-xcode-run-script-phase-d1cbea551c1b